# можно ли выполнить вычисление эллиптической кривой на GPU при помощи CUDA в python?

Tags: python, cuda, gpu

никак не могу найти материал по обработке байтовых массивов в CUDA при вычислениях на GPU. все что есть в интернете - это только математические вычисления с числами, а вот с hex преобразованным в byte ни одного примера. Может кто подскажет как это делается в Python?

вот кусочек кода, который без труда выполняется процессором в Python, но вот преобразовать его в код, вычисляемым GPU я не умею....научите пожалуйста

```
import hashlib
import codecs
import ecdsa

massive = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f']
for s1 in massive:
    for s2 in massive:
        for s3 in massive:
            itog = codecs.decode(('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001' + s1+s2+s3), 'hex')
            s = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(itog, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key
            rezult_in_bytes = s.to_string()
            put_in_hex = codecs.encode(rezult_in_bytes, 'hex')
            string = put_in_hex.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: так Вам хекс в бинарное представление перегнать или ключи эллиптические считать? или и то и другое?

Comment: спасибо за отзыв.  нужно ключи считать при помощи GPU.

Comment: байтовые массивы это тоже числа. Почти вся информация о cuda как раз о том, как их и обрабатывать. на гитхабе куча примеров, как посчитать на cuda эллиптические кривые. Новые биткоины?

Comment: приношу свой пардон но ни одного примера для CUDA GPU я не нашел...Яндекс меня тож послал куда подальше.....а stackoverflow обматерил "page not found"

Comment: ну вот же https://github.com/hhanh00/secp256k1-cl - правда питон сами прикручивайте. Если посмотреть внимательно в код, то можно понять, что он просто супер похож на это https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=140912.0 - да да, мы все знаем:)

Comment: Вельми понеже!!! Весьма вами благодарен.... Ну а код.... Он про любому будет одинаков при работе с кривыми....